# arrange/formating html and js code

Tags: javascript, linux, html

I am looking for a code/tool that can arrange/format html & Javascript. Most source-code on web-sites have only a few lines for all the coding. I like to downlaod some sites and do some formatation, so each command is in a new line.

example code:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"><title>Example</title><meta name="description" content="example page"><meta name="keywords" content="example"></head><body><header><img src="images/logo.png" id="img_logo"><nav><input type="image" src="images/hamburger.png" id="button_nav"><ul><li><a href="#" class="active">a</a></li><li><a href="b/">b</a></li><li><a href="c/">c</a></li></ul></nav></header><article><br><h1>Example</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>Etiam tristique tristique lacus in varius.<br>Donec nec vestibulum ligula.<br>Aenean turpis diam, feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus eget risus.<br>Maecenas consequat porttitor dui, vitae consequat massa imperdiet ut. elit ut tempus lobortis,<br>eros leo molestie velit, non egestas augue nulla eget erat.</p><script>function loadScript(scriptURL) {var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT');scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript');scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL);document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);}</script></article><footer><a href="#">http://example.com/</a><br></footer></body></html>
```

formated output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="description" content="example page">
    <meta name="keywords" content="example">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<img src="images/logo.png" id="img_logo">
<nav>
<input type="image" src="images/hamburger.png" id="button_nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="b/">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="c/">c</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<article>
<br>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>
Etiam tristique tristique lacus in varius.<br>
Donec nec vestibulum ligula.<br>
Aenean turpis diam, feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus eget risus.<br>
Maecenas consequat porttitor dui, vitae consequat massa imperdiet ut. elit ut tempus lobortis,<br>
eros leo molestie velit, non egestas augue nulla eget erat.</p>
<script>
function loadScript(scriptURL) {
    var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript');
    scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL);
    document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
}
</script>
</article>
<footer>
<a href="#">http://example.com/</a><br>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can make this work ?
I don't care how to archive this, as long I can do this with linux.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Do you need to do this in an automated way? There are plenty of "prettify" websites that can do this otherwise.

Comment: Plenty of Text Editors, most IDEs, and a few websites are options for formatting your code. It's not hard to find how to do this with whichever tool you use. It's a very common practice to auto-format code.

Answer (score -1):

assume You have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed, if so then https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-cli could do the job for You. See the [description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-cli#usage) for the details.